# How to keep Right Alt + Tab and Right Alt + Left Shift functionality when language is switched to Persian?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Most answers related to the right <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key are old. Some are older than 10 years.

Thus I have to ask again.

I added the Persian language/keyboard to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to change from English to Persian.

However, when in Persian I lose <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> which is almost a [universal shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab) to change apps, and I lose <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to switch back to English.

I searched and realized that it's because the right alt is [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) and it's there to enable third-level characters on the keys.

However, it's a bad decision to break the universal and widely-spread UX for this purpose.

Another disadvantage it has is related to a principle in touch typing:

```
The opposite hand should press the accompanying key
```

Now I should use my left hand to press two keys to get back to English <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> which is against touch typing rules (decreases speed), and I lose <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between apps.

I saw in one question someone suggested that I add this line to `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lalt_switch,lvl3:ralt_alt"
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from editing the predefined Persian keyboard layout yourself to remove AltGr, you could set a different keyboard combination to change keyboard layout to avoid the conflict between your current shortcut and one of your keyboard layouts. XKBOPTIONS in Ubuntu Desktop (Gnome Shell) can be set using the "Additional Layout Options" button on the "Keyboard and Mouse" tab in Gnome Tweaks (not installed by default), so you could attempt to change <kbd>AlGr</kbd> to a normal <kbd>Alt</kbd> there (under the section : "Key to choose 3rd level").

Consider also following alternative options:

- By default, in Ubuntu desktop, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is defined to change keyboard layout. Try it: it may work better.
- There are plenty of other keyboard combinations that can be configured using the XKBOPTIONS to change the keyboard layout that may work better in your use case.